# Regain the files lost due to Git reset --hard

Tags: git, gitlab

I have a remote branch, that I seem to have messed up. Here is a sequence of steps that took place in the chronological order:

- I had made a few commits on it, lets call my latest commit as **Commit #4** for simplicity
- One of my teammates pushed **Commit #5**, that I wasn't aware of
- I started working on the next steps and pushed another commit. However, I should have pulled the changes on my local before doing so *(My first mistake)*
- Sooner I pushed my changes there was a **Commit #6** consisting my code changes and an additional **Commit #7** the merge commit. This **Commit #7** reverted all the code changes performed by my colleague in **Commit #5** (I don't know why this happened; as my colleague's commits were in an entirely different set of files)
- I made a git revert on Commit #7, which Git didn't allow (as it was a merge commit). So I made git revert on Commit #6 and voila, all good! This is Commit #8 now, where the head is pointed

So this is how my commit history looked like, at this point:

- Commit #8: Revert Commit #6 <- HEAD
- Commit #7: The Merge Commit (that reverted my colleague's changes done in Commit #5)
- Commit #6: My changes over Commit #4 (since I missed pulling before my code changes)
- Commit #5: My Colleague's changes
- Commit #4: Base

Now, this is where I commited a BLUNDER!

I got into the greed of clearing up the mess in the Git History. So I executed these commands:

- git reset --hard <hash for Commit #5>
- git push -f

I expected the HEAD to point to Commit #5, from where I could start afresh

However, this is what my commit history looks like now:
Commit #6: My changes over Commit #4 (since I missed pulling before my code changes)
Commit #4: Base

Commit #5, my colleague's changes are GONE! :'(

I totally understand that `git reset --hard` is one command that needs to be executed with a lot of responsibility

Is there any hope of getting the Commit #5 changes back?

- I checked with my other colleagues to see if they have a copy of Commit #5, so that atleast we have a reference to replicate the changes. Unfortunately none of them had pulled the latest updates after commit #5
- The colleague who had authored the changes in Commit #5 will certainly have it on his local repo, but he has gone on a week long vacation
- Checked official Git documentation, but it says there is no way of reversal once `git reset --hard` is executed
- Checked `git reflog`, as expected, nothing found there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as a commit was created with your files, git never deletes the files from its store unless you ask it to with `git gc` (don't do this now!).

Are you sure there's nothing on `git reflog`? You should definitely be able to get back to at least #8 with reflog, from which you can find #5. You can also try `git fsck --lost-found` which will list you any commits which exist in git's store but are not part of any ref's history.

Comment: It wasn't straightforward, but it worked! 
It was interesting to find Commit #5 when I reflogged to Commit #8. I wasn't hoping to find it since I had never performed a `git pull`. I'm guessing that it got synced after I performed `git push`

Anyways, thanks for saving me @Leonardo, it was a great help!